# enabling cors in meanjs rest api server

Tags: angularjs, rest, cors, meanjs

I am creating an api (server side) based on [Meanjs.org latest version (0.4.0)](http://meanjs.org/) and i managed to pull off only the MEN part and create one in http://localhost:3000/api

as the frontend part i created an Angularjs in http://localhost:4000/

and then i run both application using [(P)ackage (M)anager 2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

I am trying to create a user by sending user credentials using `$resource` like this

```
angular.module('users').factory('AuthenticationResource', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup', {}, {
            post: {
                method: 'POST'
            }
        });
    }
]);
...
//In my controller
$scope.signup = function() {
    AuthenticationResource.post($scope.credentials, function(response) {
        $scope.authentication.user = response;
        $state.go($state.previous.state.name || 'home', $state.previous.params);
    });
};
```

While in my server side's `express.js`

```
'use strict';

var config         = require('../config'),
    express        = require('express'),
    ...
    cors           = require('cors');

...
module.exports.initModulesServerRoutes = function(app) {
    // Globbing routing files
    config.files.server.routes.forEach(function(routePath) {
        require(path.resolve(routePath))(app);
    });
};
module.exports.initCorsOption = function(app){
    app.options('*', cors());
};

module.exports.init = function(db) {
    // Initialize express app
    var app = express();

    ...
    // Initialise Cors options
    this.initCorsOption(app);
    // Initialize modules server routes
    this.initModulesServerRoutes(app);
    ...
    return app;
};
```

I am using [node cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to enable cors and just do `app.options('*', cors());` to enable pre-flight across-the-board

But when i am trying to do a `POST` to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup` i can see that my user is being saved to the database just fine but it doesn't give me any response and chrome console is giving me this

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access.

What did i miss?

Comment: You have 2 servers on 2 different machines?

Comment: @DoronSinai yes i am planning to on production, but currently i am testing them on one machine just running on a different port for development

Comment: Is CORE enabled on both servers?

Comment: I dont think so on the frontend angular part, how do i do it in angular?

Comment: Can you describe your architecture, what server serves the angular app, what the other server does, and which of them is on port 4000?

Comment: @DoronSinai i am not sure i understand your question, as i have stated in the question, and as i am still working all this in my local machine, both apps is being served by running a simple nodejs server on port 3000 and 4000. Or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Try setting it manual in the response and see if it works res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing app.use before all your routes:

Only express:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

If you are using npm cors:

```
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: let me try this real quick, will get back to you asap